# strange assembly goof-up involving a working, but incorrect program

Tags: assembly, gnu

```
GNU nano 2.2.4               File: argv.s                                     

.section .text

    .globl _start

_start:

    movl    %esp, %ebp

    movl    8(%ebp),%ecx
    movl    $4,%edx
    movl    $1,%ebx
    movl    $4,%eax
    int $0x80

    movl    $1,%eax
    movl    $0,%ebx
    int $0x80
```

let me preface this question by saying that i'm (obviously) new to asm and any random general advice not related to the topic is welcome...
I meant to simply read in the argv[1] from the bash terminal and print it back out. This was intended to be a test to ensure that I actually knew how to take arguments. If I enter an integer, like 2. The program prints 2O. capital 'o', not zero. why?

Comment: actually it prints 'OR' and i just noticed the 'R'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to understand that *argv[1]* is **not an integer** as you would like, but  **a string terminated null** instead! A string is sequence of bytes ending with `'\0'`.

This means that when you pass the character **2** through the cmd-line to your app, this string in memory will look like `[2][\0]`, which consists of only 2 bytes. **The problem** is that you specify the size in **%edx** as being **4**, which is not true, and will make `write()` print another 2 bytes of memory garbage to your screen.

The right way to do what you want is implement the `strlen()` function on your application. This function iterates through the stream of bytes counting how many bytes there are before the character `\0` shows up. Only then you'll be able to print the correct string. Use the number returned by `strlen()` as **%edx** when you `write()`.

Comment: A quick fix to your code, if you really just want to print the first digit of the string, change %edx to `movl $1,%edx`